# Facebook Connect with multiple FB accounts

Tags: facebook, facebook-login

I am developing a business site with Facebook Connect enabled and its working fine for me.
Now, I came across a situation where I have a user with 2 or more FB accounts and 1 of them is registered with our site.

For example

> abc.1@xyz.com    (Registered on Facebook and using FB connect on our site)
>   
> abc.2@xyz.com    (Registered on Facebook but not in our site)

With above email addresses, when a user logs in with `abc.1@xyz.com` on Facebook he gets logged in, in our site as well. But on the other side when a user logs in on Facebook with `abc.2@xyz.com` and same time logs in on our system with `abc.1@xyz.com` (without using FB connect).

Here I see a session conflict and trying to solve it. I hope you people will share your thoughts to help me out.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

At my site ours users could use

1. our site's account
2. a FB account
3. a FB account merged with our site's account (based on email).

so if someone owns more than one FB account, only the one with matching email would be merged. If someone tries to log with a FB account and that account's email is not registered within our application, a new account in our site is created.

Comment: Hi Sergi,

Here the situation is different, user is already logged in on the FB with the account which is not connect with our site, and logs in on our site with some other id (with normal login process) which is an FB connected id on our site.

Comment: Then where's the problem? I mean, there's no way to merge both accounts if they belong to different emails. The only way would be by enabling the user to manually link your site account with the facebook one, and letting him to link more than one fb account.

Answer (score 0):

I have two entities in my System (similar to the way StackOverflow is doing it)..

- Login (Facebook, Live Id, local User DB - contains NO username / pwd, but just the association)
- Account / User: The "identity" of the user in MY site (additional data which isn't on Facebook)

N Logins <--> 1 User is the cardinality of these two.

So.. YES you can merge multiple Facebook logins with ONE "local" site user.

If FB-User abc.2@xyz.com logs in on FB, you can still merge it as well with the local user abc.1@xyz.com.

So at the end you will TWO FB users mapped to the same local user..

Is that the solution you're looking for?

If not, please clarify further.